# Is there such a thing as a "floating preposition"?

Tags: syntax, prepositions, quantifiers

Floating quantifiers are quantifiers that can move away from the corresponding noun, such as "each" in "The boys hit each other" where it modifies "The boys". I am interested in prepositions in these bipartite reciprocal constructions, as in "They followed each others **onto** the stage" or "They waited **for** each other." These constructions are comparable to "They waited, each **for** the other." In this last example, the preposition is near its complement "the other", but in the earlier examples it is not.

Is there a term for these kind of "floating prepositions"? This term does not yield any results on Google Scholar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any floating of a preposition in your examples.

[McCawley](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=mccawley%20phenomena%20%22each%20other%22&source=bl&ots=uPdB3LczNl&sig=OBopFGSBK195FtoKsT2Fj8Kle24&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4oJWek93YAhWmwVQKHW8OA9gQ6AEIRTAL#v=onepage&q=mccawley%20phenomena%20%22each%20other%22&f=false) has some interesting remarks about reciprocal "each other".  In the reference, click "next" until you get to occurrences 6-9, and especially 8, which 
mentions an analysis by Dougherty attempting to relate this "each" to the one that floats.

Answer (score 1):

> *The boys hit each other.*

*Each* is not a 'floating quantifier' here (whatever that means), and *each* does not modify *boys*.

The reciprocal meaning is expressed by *each* in combination with *other*, and although *each other* is written as two orthographic words it is actually a single grammatical word.  The two components are inseparable and thus form a compound reciprocal pronoun. In your example, the compound functions as direct object of *hit.*

You may be thinking of the 'spilt' construction as in

> *They are each required to consult with the other*

which is semantically and syntactically different. Here "each" is a determinative and "other" a common noun, as opposed to a single compound pronoun.